# Showing/hiding bootstap's .hidden-xs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to create an 'up' button, which will take user to the very top of the landing page. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3U9G/)

I would like this button to be shown only on devices with large screens, so I'm using bootstrap3's `hidden-xs` class. This class applies `display: none!important` for small devices and `display: block!important` for large screens.

But now, I would like to make this button visible only, when scrolled down at least 50 pixels.
So, I would like to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() < 50) {
            // Near top.
            $('#scrollUp:visible').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            $('#scrollUp:hidden').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

jQuery's `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` apply `display: none` and `display: block`, but without `!important`.

This means that `display: block!important` applied by `.hidden-xs` is more important than css applied by `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`.

It worked great until I started using `.hidden-xs`.

I tried `$.animate({'display': 'none!important'})` instead of `$.slideUp`, but then I get another problem -- jQuery isn't properly selecting elements with `:hidden`. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHza5/2/)

Do you have an idea, what may I do wrong? Is there a way to do this nicely?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(function () {
    var timer;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50) {
                // Near top.
                console.log('If elemnt is visible it should be hidden here');
                $('#scrollUp:visible').stop(true, true).slideUp(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('hidden-xs');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('If element is hidden it should be displayed here');
                $('#scrollUp:hidden').addClass('hidden-xs').stop(true, true).slideDown(function () {
                    $(this).css('display', '')
                });
            }
        }, 100);
    });
})()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R7AeS/)